# How does "Reflect X" work in Transform effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, transform, reflection

I am unable to understand the Step 3 in this tutorial: https://vectorcove.com/illustration/brick-seamless-background-in-adobe-illustrator/

Why does 'Reflect X' bring back every alternate row in line with the first row of bricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the transform effect to create a number of copies, the transformations are cumulative, so the transforms are applied to the result of the previous copy, not the original object. They have to be, otherwise they would just stack and you'd only see one copy no matter how many copies you set.

For example, you set a horizontal move of 100pt with a number of copies. Each copy will move 100pt across *from the previous copy*, not 100pt from the original object.

The result looks like this:

[image]

"Reflect X" is also cumulative, so each copy's transformation is the inverse *of the previous copy*.

So your first copy is moved 100pt, the next copy −100pt, the next 100pt, the next −100pt and so on. Each copy's transform cancels out the previous copy's, so every other copy reverts back to the original value:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answers my question. I assumed that Reflect X would rotate around X-axis from the centre, in this case it seems to work differently.

Comment: It does work a bit differently than you would expect yes

Comment: yup, its rather interesting how its working